# Find longest sequence that does not contain a certain number

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have an array and I want to find the longest number sequence from the array that does not contain `3`:

```
#array
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,3,4,5,2,3,7]
```

I expect as result as following:

```
[4, 5, 6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: You need to provide what you have tried till now to solve it?

Comment: Your question is too general. Please show what you tried. Post the code that you wrote, even if it did not work as expected. You must demonstrate an effort to get help.

Comment: the longest sequence is the longest distance between 2 consecutive threes or the endpoints

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this, I would make groups with [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and take the longest one:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,3,4,5,2,3,7] 

groups = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x!=3) if k]
max(groups, key = len)

# [4, 5, 6, 5, 4]
```

Of course there are many other way. If you want to manually loop through the list, you can just keep track of the current longest seen:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,3,4,5,2,3,7] 

cur = []
longest = cur
for n in a:
    if n != 3:
        cur.append(n)
        if len(cur) > len(longest):
            longest = cur
    else:
        cur = []

print(longest) #[4, 5, 6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find sequence (specifically subsequence) then taking all elements which are not `3` will be the result.

But it seems you want to find sub array. Following is my implementation for the same in python

```
def findLargestSubArray(arr, k):
    # collect all the index position of k in arr
    kPos = [i for i in range(len(arr)) if arr[i] == k]
    largest = 0
    left = -1
    right = -1
    # size of subarray to the left of 1st instance of k
    if len(kPos) > 0:
        largest = kPos[0] - 1
        left = 0
        right = kPos[0]
    for i in range(1, len(kPos)):
        # size of subarray between ith & (i-1)th instance of k
        currSize = kPos[i] - kPos[i-1] - 1
        if largest < currSize:
            largest = currSize
            left = kPos[i-1] + 1
            right = kPos[i]
    # size of subarry to the right of last instance of k
    if largest < len(arr) - kPos[-1] - 1:
        largest = len(arr) - kPos[-1] - 1
        left = kPos[-1] + 1
        right = len(arr)
    return arr[left: right]


x = [3,3]
print(findLargestSubArray(x, 3))
```